# Is it possible in Objective-C to find allocated objects at runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reflection, nstimer, nsrunloop

I want to stop an NSTimer that is allocated from inside a static library, so I don't have a reference to said object. But I know it's there as I can see the allocation in Instruments.
Is there a way I can get the references of all Timers at runtime. Or is it possible to get all scheduled timers of a run loop?

Comment: Not without knowing the memory address of the object.

Comment: @borrrden So I wonder how Instruments does it?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible in any practical way. Instruments works by instrumenting the runtime with a hook that logs all object allocations and deallocations.

While it is possible for you to create a similar mechanism, it isn't useful outside of debugging.

First, it would have significant overhead.  Noticeable overhead.

Secondly, you couldn't do anything with the information safely as anything you so would make assumptions about the implementation that'd lead to crashes or undefined behavior.